# Is there a proper ideal of $B(H)$ that contains a proper projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space and $\mathcal{I}$ be a proper closed two-sided ideal of $B(H)$. Can $\mathcal{I}$ contain a projection for a infinite dimensioal proper closed subspace? If $H$ is not separable (or $\mathcal{I}$ not closed) while all other conditions remain the same, will the conclusion change? What if $\mathcal{I}$ is only one-sided (other conditions remain the same)?

(**Added**) This question is inspired by **Corollary 5.11** in *Banach Algebra Technique in Operator Theory* written by **Ronald G. Douglas**. This corollary claims that in an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert Space the ideal of compact operators $\mathcal{K}$ is the only proper closed two-sided ideal in $B(H)$. The proof first assumes that $T \in \mathcal{I}$ and $T$ is **NOT** compact. Hence by the converse of **Lemma 5.8** in the range of $T$ there is a closed infinite dimensional subspace say $M$. Define $  S_0: M \rightarrow H, S_0(Tv) = v\,\implies\,S_0 \in B(M)$ according to closed mapping theorem. Define $S\,\vert_M = S_0, S\,\vert_{M^{\perp}} = 0\,\implies\,TS = P_M \in \mathcal{I}$. At last the proof claims that hence $\mathcal{I}$ contains the identity mapping. I am not sure if the last statement is correct.

**Lemma 5.8**: $H$ is a $\infty - dim$ Hilbert space. $T$ a compact operator iff $ran(T)$ contains **NO** closed $\infty - dim$ subspace.

In the original text there is only $\implies$ direction but the converse is also true. Let $H_{\leq 1}$ be the closed unit ball of $H$ and hence $\overline{TH_{\leq 1}}$ is a finite dimensional closed and bounded subspace and hence compact (with respect to the original topology).

Comment: The application of Lemma 5.8 is wrong as written; what is being used is the converse of Lemma 5.8.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I should state it more precisely there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{I}$ contains a projection $P$ onto an infinite-dimensional closed subspace $M$.  In particular, $\dim M=\dim H=\aleph_0$ since $H$ is separable, so we can pick a Hilbert space isomorphism $U:M\to H$.  Extend $U$ to an operator $T:H\to H$ which vanishes on $M^\perp$, and let $S:H\to H$ be the composition of $U^{-1}:H\to M$ with the inclusion $M\to H$.  Then $TPS=1$, so $1\in\mathcal{I}$ and the ideal is not proper.

This argument does not use the assumption that $\mathcal{I}$ is closed, but it does use the assumption that $H$ is separable and $\mathcal{I}$ is two-sided.  If $H$ has uncountable dimension, then the set of operators whose range is separable forms a proper closed two-sided ideal and contains projections onto infinite-dimensional subspaces.  If $\mathcal{I}$ is only a one-sided ideal, then it could be the ideal of all operators that vanish on $M^\perp$ (for a left ideal) or operators whose range is contained in $M$ (for a right ideal).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have tried applying the same idea and in fact it is not too complicated. Also your examples are very helpful :)